# Flickering in IE 11 when changing HTML 5 <video/> src

Tags: javascript, html, video

I don't know if anyone will be able to point me in the right direction,  but I am currently having some issues with IE when I am trying to switch between videos.

I am developing some training material, which will essential show Step X of Y of a maintenance procedure.  Clicking the "Next Step" button will move on an play the next video in the sequence, the previous button the previous, and so on.

The `MP4` video playback is excellent in Firefox, has an occasional "white flash" as the media changes in Google and utterly terrible in IE, with almost a delay in switching the two `.src` values when I the click - the previous video seems to play a few frames before beginning the updated source.

I am using the `preload = "auto"` attribute, but I'm not sure if there is a better way of preloading video to avoid these switch over flashes?

Comment: Provide us some code so we can see what's potentially causing the problem.